# Weird AutoLayout Issue for UICollectionView

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview, autolayout

This is my first time asking a Stack Overflow Question, so hopefully I do it right.

Currently, I am having a weird Auto Layout Issue that makes a UICollectionView behave differently depending on what size iPhone I am loading. The app I am creating is a Schedule app, and in the app you're able to select a specific day to view or create a schedule for that day. Currently, all works well on the bigger iPhones, pretty much iPhone 11 and up.

I have a piece of code in the View Controller that selects the middle item in the array, which is today's date, and selects the middle item in the CollectionView.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        dateCollectionView.selectItem(at: IndexPath.init(item: CalendarModel.CURRENT_DAY, section: 0), animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    }
```

It ends up looking like this: 
[AutoLayout Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aps0O.png)

But, when I chose a smaller screen, like the iPhone 8, you can see that it didn't go to the middle of the calendar array, like it did on the iPhone 11 and instead shows the CollectionView at the beginning of the array.

Looks like this:
[AutoLayout Doesn't Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr2oV.png)

If I then select the iPhone 8 in the Interface Builder and "Reset to Suggested Constraints", it then works properly on the iPhone 8 and not on the iPhone 11. Here are some pictures showing that:

Selecting iPhone 8 in the Interface Builder:
[iPhone 8 Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd43b.png)

iPhone 8 Now Works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lJ8H.png)

This leads me to believe that it is a constraint issue. I'm pretty new to AutoLayout and have been reading up on documentation to try and figure this out, but can't seem to crack it just yet. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you setting the constraints via code or storyboard?

Comment: @Frankenstein I'm setting the constraints fully through Storyboard. Any idea what it may be?

Comment: With this limited info, I can't tell unless it has occurred to me. Could reproduce the bug on playgrounds and post the code?

Comment: @Frankenstein I'm not sure how I could re-create the bug, if I was able to link you to my public repository for this project, would that be helpful?

Comment: Sure maybe, I could take a look.

Comment: @Frankenstein Thanks a bunch! I'm having a real hard time here, the link is: https://github.com/julianboyko/Power-Planner

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before and the reason was setting the minimum spacing for collection view here:

[image: storyboard spacing]

Try to set it to zero and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried setting it to zero but the same issue persisted. 